# What exactly is thread-count parameter in maven

Tags: maven

I am new to maven and I am not quite sure what is the difference between thread-count ="1" and thread-count = "2"

If I set thread-count ="2" , it means that the same test will run on the same time on both of the phones?

Is it possible to run a test on one phone and when it finished, to run the same test on the second phone?

Thanks

Comment: Why the down votes without comments?  Shay what have you tried?  Your code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Without further information my best guess is [Parallel builds in Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3):

> *Maven 3.x has the capability to perform parallel builds.*
>
> ...
>
> *This build-mode analyzes your project's dependency graph and schedules modules that can be built in parallel according to the dependency graph of your project.*

The next best guess is [Run appium tests parallelly](https://discuss.appium.io/t/run-appium-tests-parallelly/4079).

And the next is [TestNG's documentation, 5.10.2 - Parallel tests, classes and methods](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests):

> The *parallel* attribute on the `<suite>` tag can take one of following values:
>
> ```
> <suite ... thread-count="5">
> ```